# Divide unique value by frequency of multiple values

Tags: excel, countif

I have searched everywhere for this one but can't find a solution.  Please help!  I have used this site a lot and know there are a lot of clever people out there!

I would like to divide the number of times a unique value appears in a column by the number of times a selected multiple values appear in a column.

For example, I would like to know the percentage of times the value 2 appears out of the number of times values 1,2,3,4,5 appear (but not 6 in this list):

```
1
2
2
2
3
5
6
6
```

2 appears three times, but I want this as a percentage of 6 not 8, the correct answer being 50% not 37.5%.

I have tried `=(COUNTIF(Jan!C7,2))/(COUNT(Jan!C7,"<6"))` which seems to work when entered directly into the spreadsheet (with the correct column labels) but not when entered in VBA as `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(COUNTIF(Jan!C7,1))/(COUNT(Jan!C7,"<6"))"` - it throws back an error.

Many thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `C7:C14` are

```
1
2
2
2
3
5
6
6
```

then `=(COUNTIF(C7:C14,"=2"))/(COUNTIF(C7:C14,"<6"))` will display `.5` which is 50%

[image]

further,

to use this in VBA you need

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=(COUNTIF(C7:C14,""=2""))/(COUNTIF(C7:C14,""<6""))"
```

Note: you need to wrap `"` with another `"` to escape the double quote inside a string

Comment: Double quotes!! Ah-ha, thank you so much, I never knew about those... worked a treat, you are a star!

Comment: @user3009700 im glad i could help. Here, on stackoverflow we say thank you by [**accepting answer which helped us**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).